# Problem with linking to other project in Android Eclipse environment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classpath

I am developing an Android application as an Eclipse project that uses classes from another Eclipse Android project I already have. When I originally imported it (`New Project > Android Project > From Existing Source`), it had a bunch of errors, but when I did `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` and went to the projects tab and added the other project, the errors went away.  Unfortunately, when I ran the application, I got the following error in DDMS:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [package name].Config
> [stack trace]
> ```

Is there something I'm supposed to add to the manifest telling it to look at the other package? If so, where would that be added?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  It turns out that if I add the compiled class files into a JAR file using Eclipse's export command and then link to external jars in the Java Build Path, it works without having to change the Android Manifest at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the File -> Import...

Then go to "Existing projects into Workspace" and choose the root directory of the project.
The one where are the src,res... folders

Comment: The project is already in the workspace so that's not the problem.  In fact, the project compiles and installs properly.  But as soon as I make the first call on an external class, the app crashes with a NoClassDefFoundError. Other ideas?

Comment: Oh OK. I misunderstood the question. I never tried that, but (unfortunately) I have some experience with NoClassDefFoundError. Are the two projects in the emulator/cell phone you are using. That could be one of the reasons.

Comment: Both applications are installed on the phone.  Do I need to remove one?

Comment: No. The problem of the NoClassDefFoundError is because your app can't find the other project in Runtime. You compile it in the computer where it finds the other project but then when it runs doesn't find it. My opinion is that it should be treated in the Manifest. In the application tab try adding a new application node. Add a new Activity and then on Name*: Browse for the other project main Activity (Don't forget to uncheck the box in the bottom that says to only find activities in your project). If you need the activity. If you just need the classes why not just copy them.

Answer (score 0):

Your second project should be a library. Open project properties, select the Android tab and check "is library".

In your main project, open its properties, select Android tab also and click on `Add` in the library section and add your second project.

Comment: Do you see `NameOfYourSecondProject_src [Android Library]` in your fist project's navigator? In your Java Build Path, make sure you removed your reference to the second project in "Projects". It should be only in "source"

Comment: I think this method didn't work because I'm doing some fancy AIDL/JNI stuff.

Comment: It is possible, because adding the compiled JAR to your classpath is indeed working but not very practical if you need to often update your library.